# Mapear una entidad en symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Quetal, tengo un problema y es que antes en symfony3 se corria en la consola:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import MiBundle yml
```

y generaba y mapear una entidad de la base de datos pero en Symfony 4 me el comando en la consola siempre es el mismo, pero los bundles ya no se ocupan en la ultima version por lo cual el comando anterior tal cual esta ya no funciona, 
Alguien me podria ayudar...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A partir de la versión 4 ya no estará disponible porque se supone que se debe empezar a crear las entidades y luego mapear -> hacias la base de datos.

Lo que recomiendan es crear las entidades con anotaciones y luego ejecutar

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

En symfony 4 es posible realizar esta acción de la siguiente forma:

Para anotaciones:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import 'App\Entity' annotation --path=src/Entity
```

Y para generar los getters y setters:

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

[Referencia](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)